# Detect incorrect file type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, file

My application is allowed users to upload jpeg/png files.I must to detect files with changed extensions.For example: if somebody take example.txt file and change his name to example.jpg
so it not enough to check this file by javascript, need server solution. How i can do this?
Can somebody show code example? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file with not correct format, for your application (considering post) is an *exceptional* situation. So I would think about simple `try/catch` block where you *try* to load image of *declared* format. If exception ocures (say) => notify to a user, that the file seems to be in non correct format.

Comment: Hi.You are write. This is write solution for this situation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this most of the time using magic bytes in the beginning of files. See this link for a list of these numbers for different file types: http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

For instance, JPEG files start with `ff d8 ff e0`, and png files start with `89 50 4e 47`.

Comment: Here's C# example from the interwebs ;) http://softwaredevelopment.gr/764/get-image-file-type-from-magic-numbers/